# Splash screen is visible between navigation from one page to another xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm working on Xamarin forms PCL project and I wanted to implement a splash screen in my project. I'm following the below example for the Xamarin.android part
[xamarin forms splash screen android](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/)

when I'm navigating from one page to another page, Splash screen is visible between the pages. Any solution for the above issue.

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/SplashScreen"
```

**SplashActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "sso_app_1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
          MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true,
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class SplashActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you need to finish the splash screen before moving further ?

Comment: @Lucifer I tried adding Finish() after StartActivity, no luck. It's still visible.

Comment: Hi All, Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180471/splash-screen-dispose-remove-after-loaded and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splash screen dispose/remove after loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180471/splash-screen-dispose-remove-after-loaded)